# Historical data / logs on what RAM and disk storage used to be in Linux?

Tags: logging, memory, hard-drive

Is there any historical data / logs in my VPS that can show what the RAM and disk storage used to be?

My hosting provider reduced my RAM and disk storage from 1.5GB and 150GB to 1GB and 100GB because they recently re-provisioned it without adding up the promotions which I signed up for. I need them to add those 50% increase in RAM and disk back but they seem to need proof that I actually had 1.5GB and 150GB before.

Thanks!

Comment: `but they seem to need proof that I actually had 1.5GB and 150GB before.`  They sound like asshats.  That right there would probably be enough to get me to move to a different host, TBH.

Comment: @HopelessN00b, it's Wiredtree.com. The people are pretty nice but this is really frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

We can't know what logs you have. But most likely, you will have logs of the VPS booting, and those logs will contain the amount of memory and the size of the disks.

Check all files in `/var/log` for entries like the following:

```
total RAM covered: 8192M

Memory: 8155988k/9437184k available (6294k kernel code, 1049608k absent, 231588k reserved, 6911k data, 1032k init)

sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
```

I would start with `dmesg` to see what messages your kernel spits out. Find the ones that show how much memory and disk space it has. Then use `grep` to find any past instances of those messages that were logged. (Note that logfiles might be compressed. You may want to make copies of them, uncompress them, and search in that location, removing them when you're done.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using CentOS 5.8, I didn't see anything "ram" or "memory" nor "disk" in the dmseg results. Nor do I find anything in /var/log that looks like what you posted by 'find /var/log -type f -exec grep "RAM" {} \;' or "memory", etc. Any idea?

Comment: @kavoir.com: Most likely, you're just not looking right. Check the kernel logs from your last reboot (they may have scrolled out of the `dmesg` buffer). You will find log entries that describe your RAM and HD sizes. You will then know what to search for. It could be as simple as you searching for "memory" instead of "Memory" or the log files being compressed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have some receipt (email) saying which price-plan + promotions you signed up. That would be, I would guess, the most promising way to convince them.

If you don't have that, then you could have some data from the sar (http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar) or collectd or some other tool, but these can be easily changed, so being the VPS provider, I wouldn't had much trust in such data.

I bet the VPS provider has some measuring tool. But the data may not be available to you.

Comment: I've looked through all the email archives but they didn't include any specs of the VPS in the messages.